# ¿Cómo obtener el mayor número posible con las cifras de un número entero de tres digitos?

Tags: java, algoritmos, java-8, intellij-idea

Diseñe un algoritmo que lea un número entero de 3 cifras, y forme el mayor número posible con las cifras del número ingresado.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Variable
    int numero;
    int cifras;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Introduce un número de tres cifras: ");
        numero = reader.nextInt();
    } while (numero < 99);

    String numberText = String.valueOf(numero);
    System.out.println(numberText);
    
}
```

Solo me hace falta obtener el mayor número posible con las cifras del número ingresado.

Comment: por lo que entiendo, necesitas ingresar 3 números ej: 385 y dentro de esos 3 números se debe identificar el mayor numero con las 3 combinaciones que en este caso sería 853?

Answer (score 0):

La forma mas sencilla de realizar esto es convertir el numero a un arreglo de caracteres, y ordenarlo descendentemente mediante:

```
  Arrays.sort(numeros, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

de esta forma obtendràs el mayor numero posible al imprimir los valores del Array.

Este serìa el mètodo:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    int numero;
    int cifras;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Introduce un número de tres cifras: ");
        numero = reader.nextInt();
    } while (numero < 99);
    
  
    //Convierte numero introducido a una cadena de caracteres.  
    String numerosString = String.valueOf(numero);
    
    //Crea arreglo de numeros.  
    Object[] numeros = new Object[String.valueOf(numero).length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < numerosString.length(); i++) {
            numeros[i] = numerosString.charAt(i);
     }
    
    //Ordena Array en orden descendente
    Arrays.sort(numeros, Collections.reverseOrder()); 

    String numberText = "";
    for (Object c:numeros) { 
        numberText +=c;
    }
    
     System.out.println("obtener el mayor número posible es: " + numberText);

     reader.close();
        
 }
```

Recuerda siempre cerrar el Scanner.

Ejemplo:

[image: System.out.println("El mayor número posible es: " + numberText);]